# how to get selected items id in jquery selectables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This may be a simple question but i could not find a solution.I wand to get the selected list item id when i select it in jquery selectables.my list is like this

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <li id="one">
        <div>one</div>
        <div>two</div>
        <div>three</div>
    </li>
    <li id="two">
        <div>one</div>
        <div>two</div>
       <div>three</div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

My jquery code is like this

```
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({filter: 'li'});
```

Now what i need is get the id of selected li.ex:if i select on first li then i want the id of it.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
    selected: function(event, ui) {
            alert(ui.selected.id)
        }
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LXYUT/2/ (choose item 1)